# Postgres JSON query not behaving as expected in DataGrip

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with a JSON field inside. Here some example of the data:

```
"{\"client_id\": 1, \"garment_id\": \"14\", \"garment_model\": \"RG\", \"is_bottom\": false, \"options\": [{\"key\": \"size\", \"value\": \"S\"}]}"
"{\"client_id\": 1, \"garment_id\": \"33\", \"garment_model\": \"01\", \"options\": [{\"key\": \"size\", \"value\": \"M\"}]}"
```

I'm hoping to get the list of client ids with this query:

```
SELECT payload->'client_id'
FROM garment LIMIT 10;
```

But instead of a list of `client_id` values all I get is `NULL`:

[image]

I also tried this query:

```
SELECT payload->>'\"client_id\"'
FROM garment LIMIT 10;
```

**My question is: What can I do to get the expected results of a list of client ids?**

Comment: I don't know what your example data actually represents.  Did you add the outermost double quotes and escape the inner ones for presentation purposes, or are those literally present in your data?

Comment: If the data isn't valid JSON, or the field does not exist then you can expect NULLs. I'd check the JSON validity.

Comment: Apparently, that's the problem. Thanks! Feel free to convert your comment to an answer and I will select it

Comment: Pleased you found the cause. I' have added a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data isn't valid JSON, or the field does not exist then you can expect NULLs. I'd check the JSON validity.

```
SELECT json_typeof(payload) 
FROM garment LIMIT 10;
```

If any of the values are not of type json, it means that they are not valid JSON data.